# Google Apps Script - When new row containing data with specific keywords is added to Sheet 1, move that to a new row in a new corresponding sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I am using Google Sheets to evaluate data from a Zoho Form. I would like to sort the raw data from spreadsheet 1 ('Raw Data') into 3 new spreadsheets depending on 2 specific keywords found in 2 different columns in 'Raw Data'.

For context - the keywords for the first column (column 'G') are:

1. Ordered
2. Stock
3. Preordered

the keywords for the second column (column 'F') are:

1. B2B
2. B2C

There are a total of 6 possibilites that need to be accounted for: ordered & B2B, ordered & B2C, stock & B2B, stock & B2C, preordered & B2B, preordered & B2C.

If for instance a form is submitted for 'Ordered' and 'B2B', then a specific succession of rows must be transferred to the corresponding 'Ordered' spreadsheet because of Zoho Forms' nature of staggering the submitted information horizontally in the 'Raw Data' sheet. These rows will change depending on which one of the 6 combinations is chosen in the Form.

The 3 new spreadsheets will be named according to the keywords found in column 'G'.

So far I have been working with a Query in the new sheets to pull the needed information from the 'Raw Data' spreadsheet, however this hasn't proven to work as intended as Zoho Forms creates a new row rather than filling an existing one, causing the query to skip the newly created row and therefore not pulling any data.

Here is the Query, maybe it'll help identify what I am looking for:

=IF('Raw Data'!G6="Ordered", IF('Raw Data'!F6="B2B",QUERY('Raw Data'!A6:DN6,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T ORDER BY C desc LIMIT 1"), QUERY('Raw Data'!A6:DN6,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU ORDER BY C desc LIMIT 1")))

I have found someone who posted a Script similar to what I am looking for, however it is missing that conditional aspect to it. Here is the script, maybe it can serve as a good starting point. (all credit for this code goes to *Mike Steelson*):

```
function moveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var rng = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A2:C2')
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getLastRow()+1,1,1,3).setValues(rng.getValues())
  rng.clearContent()
}
```

I am quite new to building these sort of things so please forgive me if the Query and my overall explanation isn't the best, if you have any questions I'll try my best to elaborate!

Cheers,
Rupert.

Comment: Where is the zoho form located?

Comment: Hi Cooper, what exactly do you mean? The form itself is accessible through a public link hosted on Zoho Forms directly.

Comment: So I  guess they have an api to access the data or can they link directly to a google form?

Comment: Google Sheets is hooked up to Zoho Forms as an extension thorugh Zoho Forms itself, so I am guessing Zoho is using a Google API to do this. There is no Google Form in play.

Comment: I meant to ask if it is linked to a google sheet

Comment: Yes! I linked the Zoho Form to a Google Sheet that I created, once the first form is submitted Zoho Forms creates a new spreadsheet in the designated Sheet.

Comment: Does that action trigger an onFormSuibmit Trigger?